# ImageCaching on IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, allocation

I've some trouble with memory on my app. I've checked Instruments to get more clue about this issue and i've found that 79% of my memory is used by this :

[image: instruments]

So i've searched on Google and some people said that is image caching which saved in memory all my images. Maybe it comes from my allocation ?

Here is how i call my images :

```
info = [InfoModel getInfo:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.idEnigme]];

    myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"res/img/%@", [info objectForKey:@"path1"]]];
    myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];

    myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 400);

    [self.scrollView addSubview:myImageView];
```

Info is a class where i parse a Json file where are my path to images.

Thanks for helping, this drives me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

iOS automatically caches your image for future use when you call `imageNamed:`

As discussed in a few places, including here:[Does UIImageView cache images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270277/does-uiimageview-cache-images)

You can get around this caching if you know you are only going to create it once by using

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:nil]]
```

instead

Comment: When i use `UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:` instead of `imageNamed` and my image doesn't appear anymore...

Comment: You have to pass it the path of the file instead of the file name, I'll edit my ansewr

Comment: It works. I'll test on every image of my app and i'll post my feedback.

Comment: This means you have other general memory issues. I recommend you perform heap shot analysis. See http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode and search heap shot

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about that too much, the UIImage cache is cleared when the app receives a low memory warning. It's all handled automatically, so any images that are no longer in use will be flushed from memory at this point.

So if your app is crashing from running out of memory it is not likely because the OS is caching images that are no longer in use.

You can handle your own caching of images by using initWithData instead of imageNamed but I doubt this solution will help you.

Comment: I've already tried something like this with imageWithContentsOfFile and it doesn't solved my problem. Have you any idea where it would come from ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm very worried about the following screen. When i launch "Instruments" in Allocations mode, i see every image of my app adding to "Living". I really don't understand how it could be possible... [image]

Comment: Look into the living objects and open the right panel of instruments from the top right corner. Look at the call stack and see if you're releasing your images properly

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem and i solved it. I'll explain you what was the problem, maybe it could help someone.

The real problem was my UIImage init. Initially i allocated my UIImage in method like the following code :

```
NSString* fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", name, number, ext];
            UIImage *myImageHeader = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:nil]];
            UIImageView *myImageViewHeader = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImageHeader];

            myImageViewHeader.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 277);

            [self.scrollView addSubview:myImageViewHeader];
```

Finally i've decided to create a UIImageview in my .h via a property and to set it in my method, like this :

```
#.h
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *headerImage;

#.m
[self.headerImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:nil inDirectory:nil]]];
```

By this way i saved a lot of memory but i still have leaks. So i decided to delete the image in my UIImageView after use :

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            self.headerImage.image = nil;
        });
```

Now, my app only use 8mb of memory and manage memory correctly.

Thx for helping !