# UITableView with huge number of image

Tags: ios, image, uitableview

My app needs to display huge number of images(about 2000) in a UITableView. Basically, I use the following code to construct my UITableViewCell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    } 

    // Some Operations...

    NSString *path = [self.dataArray jk_objectWithIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    cell.imageView.image = img;

    return cell;
}
```

This works but when the tableview loads, memory increase fast and it seems that all the images is loaded to the memory.

Is there any good ideas to deal with this? I just want to save the memory.

BTW, anyone knows what the common way is to achieve this need? I think loading all the images to memory is the stupidest way... And the code I initial rows of tableview is the following:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (!_isLoading) {
        return self.dataArray.count; // about 2000... That's terrible
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does your image come from Local or WebAPI?

Comment: Use https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage if you want load image from server

Comment: My images come from Local.

Comment: The problem that you have is coming from the image cache. Every image is cached and it increases the used memory. I think you can try to create different image caches and to clean the caches which are far from the current index of the table view.

Comment: @m1sh0 Thanks for your suggestion. When the tableview didn't come to screen, everything is OK. The dataArray contains the paths of the images, not the image itself.

Comment: @dahiya_boy Could you explain it more detail...?

Comment: yes but every time when you display an image the image is cached in the default cache and this is the default behavior. And once when you close the view controller the cache continues keeping the images. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8272227/1856499

Comment: I don't have anything more specific. But you can check here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage  . And on init(named ... ) it says  "Because these methods cache the image data automatically, ". I have such a memory problem when I did animation with 50 images.

Comment: @m1sh0 I have already called -imageWithContentsOfFile: not -init(named ... ). Still, you bring me a new idea for this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code.

- First, and most important, the images are large but the *display* of the images in the table is small. That's wrong. You should load the image only at the size you actually need for display.
- Second, images are cached by default. You need to prevent the caching of these images as they are loaded.

You can easily do both of those things in your `cellForRowAt` by using the ImageIO framework.

Comment: ImageIO can prevent caching all images by default?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out a way to this question. Add these lines of code to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
CGRect rectInTableView = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGRect rectInSuperview = [tableView convertRect:rectInTableView toView:[tableView superview]];
    if ( rectInSuperview.origin.y > SCREEN_HEIGHT || rectInSuperview.origin.y + rectInSuperview.size.height < 0 ) {
        cell.imageView.image = self.placeholder;
    } else {
        NSString *path = [self.dataArray jk_objectWithIndex:indexPath.row];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
        cell.imageView.image = img;
    }
```

First I check whether the cell is shown on the screen. If yes, the imageView show my data images. If not, it show the placeholder instead. Also, the placeholder is init with `[UIImage imageNamed:]`. This is the best way because it will be used frequently.